# Check Activity info in the MyFirebaseMessagingService when App is in foreground

Tags: android, firebase, android-service, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am working on a chat app. I am retrieving chats directly from the server. I am listening for new nodes. So, If, the app is in foreground and the notification is from the same user with whom I am talking. I don't want to show the notification. How can I check in Service which Activity is running in foreground and content of that activity.

Comment: If you are interested, I have exaplained in one of my tutorials step by step, how you can send **[notifications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA&t=3s&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=17)** to specific users using Cloud Firestore and Node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences to save current running activity of your app in onResume, onPause.

like below:

```
 @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putBoolean("isCurrent", false).commit();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putBoolean("isCurrent", false).commit();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putBoolean("isCurrent", true).commit();
}
```

and then in your service:

```
if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("isCurrent", false)) {
            return;
}
```